# I can't figure out what is wrong with this prime checker

Tags: python, primes

I am trying to solve Project Euler problem 3, I am new to coding so I'm sure this could be more optimized. Essentially, I'm trying to loop through every number between 1 and the sqrt of the number to figure out if it's prime, my debug is consistently saying that it only checks if it's divisible by 1, What am I doing wrong?

```
# Project Euler Problem #3
# Largest prime factor
# What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?
import math
primelist = []
n = 1

while n < 775147:
    n += 1
    m = int(math.sqrt(n))
    if 600851475143 % n == 0:
        if n % 2 != 0:

             for i in range(1,m):
                print (i)
                if n % i == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    primelist.append(n)
```

Comment: The value of `i` starts at 1, and `n % 1` is always zero, so control breaks out of the for loop immediately.

Comment: Great. That explains why it only checks for divisibility by 1, but the real issue is that it shouldn’t test that at all. It should test from 2 to sqrt(N).

Comment: Yeah Grismar's answer below helped me out with that.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in range(1, m):` needs to be `for i in range(2, m + 1):`, as you don't want to test for `1` and `m + 1` should be included.

For example, when `n == 9`, `m` will be `3`, which is what you're after - `range(2, m)` would exclude `m`.